# Create a second Jail on FreeBSD?

Tags: networking, freebsd, jails

I recently created a Jail on FreeBSD 11 Release, I used the steps listed on the ezjail section of the handbook [The handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/jails-ezjail.html), specifically:

```
echo cloned_interfaces="lo1" >> /etc/rc.conf 
service netif cloneup
pkg install ezjail
echo ezjail_enable="YES" >> /etc/rc.conf
service ezjail start
ezjail-admin create database 'lo1|127.0.1.1,em0|192.168.0.5'
ezjail-admin start database
```

So far it works great, but I have some questions regarding the creation of a second jail:

- do I need to repeat steps 1 and 2 but replacing lo1 with lo2?
- on the create command should the parameters be 'lo2|127.0.2.1, em0|192.168.0.6'?
- where does 127.0.1.1 comes from?

Answer (score 2):

Figured out by myself,  instead of:

```
echo cloned_interfaces="lo1" >> /etc/rc.conf
```

I needed to use:

```
echo cloned_interfaces="lo1 lo2" >> /etc/rc.conf
```